# Efficient implementation for: "Python For Else Loop" in Java

Tags: java, python, if-statement, for-loop

In Python there is an efficient `for .. else` loop implementation described
[here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

Example code:

```
for x in range(2, n):
    if n % x == 0:
        print n, 'equals', x, '*', n/x
        break
else:
    # loop fell through without finding a factor
    print n, 'is a prime number'
```

In Java I need to write more code to achieve the same behavior:

```
finishedForLoop = true;
for (int x : rangeListOfIntegers){
    if (n % x == 0)
    {
        //syso: Some printing here
        finishedForLoop = false
        break;
    }
}
if (finishedForLoop == true){
    //syso: Some printing here
}
```

Is there any better implementation similar to Python `for .. else` loop in Java?

Comment: You can replace `if (finishedForLoop == true)` with `if (finishedForLoop)`. No need to test for `true`, the `if` statement does that implicitly :)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

It's done like this:

```
class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 13;
        found: {
            for (int x : new int[]{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12})
                if (n % x == 0) {
                    System.out.println("" + n + " equals " + x + "*" + (n/x));
                    break found;
                }
            System.out.println("" + n + " is a prime number");
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
$ javac A.java && java A
13 is a prime number
```

Comment: Why the labeled `break`? There is only one loop to break out of.

Comment: @FredOverflow: it's not breaking out of the loop, but the enclosing block.

Comment: @FredOverflow To elaborate on Eric's comment: an unlabeled break would continue on the statement that follows the loop and still flow through the `println` statement.

Answer (score 15):

When I need to do something like this, if no extra information is needed, I typically try to break it out into a separate method - which can then return `true`/`false` or alternatively either the value found, or null if it's not found. It doesn't *always* work - it's very context-specific - but it's something worth trying.

Then you can just write:

```
for (...) {
    if (...) {
       return separateMethod();
    }
}
return null; // Or false, or whatever
```

Comment: for cases when a different method is not ideal, you can always "break out" of the loop using a labelled break... but it is very rare to see this in practice.

Answer (score 2):

No. That's the simplest. It's not *that* complicated, it's just syntax.

Comment: also, even if you find something "simpler", it will also be "smart". And "smart" is difficult-to-read

Comment: +1, Yes you are right, i am still interested in more "smart" solutions:-)

Comment: I don't see what's not smart about using the minimum syntax. To answer your question straight, no there is nothing simpler and there is nothing smarter.

Answer (score 2):

Since java8 there is a way to write this with "nearly no" code:

```
if(IntStream.range(2, n).noneMatch(x -> n % x == 0)) {
   System.out.println(n + " is a prime number");
}
```

BUT: this would be less efficient than the classical looping-with-break-and-flag method.

Answer (score -1):

No, there is no mechanism like this in Java