# What ways are there of executing code only if no break occurres in a for loop in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop

So in python one can put an else statement after a for-loop to only execute code if no break occurred. Is there something similar in Java? Or do you have to use an extra boolean like this:

```
b = true;
for () {
if (conditional) {
    b = false;
    break;
}
if (b) {
    doSomething();
}
```

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire, it is not a duplicate of the question you mentioned.

Comment: My copy paste skills have found their match... I meant this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069402/efficient-implementation-for-python-for-else-loop-in-java

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire, all right, you know you linked a different question.

Comment: @OliverGrégoire Weird, I did google before hand and searched the stack overflow website. I must have phrased it wrong then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Java has nothing similar, so if you really need to imitate that behaviour you need to use an extra variable.

However it's worth considering that since different programming languages have different idioms, converting directly from one to another may not result in code that fits the style of the destination language. Therefore depending on the actual problem being solved, it may be suitable to use a `for-else` in python, but a different idiom in Java.

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz Well...yes, you didn't?

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz see http://psung.blogspot.fr/2007/12/for-else-in-python.html

Answer (score 2):

A variable is definitely the most readable way to achieve that but here's an alternative I came up with:

```
loop:
{
    for (...) {
        if (...) break loop;
    }
    // no 'break loop' occurred
}
```

Comment: Very good and simple.

Comment: Not very idiomatic in Java. I think this would confuse many people.